# my javascript only works when it is in a function

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

i have some html and javascript, but the javascript only executes when I put it in an onclick. i am trying to just create a new list element.

dosent work:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var newElement = document.createElement("li");
newElement.innerHTML = "hello";
var boo = document.getElementById("moo");
boo.appendChild(newElement);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="moo">
    <li>loo</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

does work:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hoo(){
var newElement = document.createElement("li");
newElement.innerHTML = "hello";
var boo = document.getElementById("moo");
boo.appendChild(newElement);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onclick="hoo()">
<ul id="moo">
    <li>loo</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

What am i doing wrong that doesn't let it execute on its own? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is working fine for me...http://jsfiddle.net/t3Mfc/

Comment: Because when your javascript exceute your element is not present in dom

Comment: Try adding the script tag, just before the end of body tag, so that DOM is ready and loaded. Or try using, document.onready event for execution.

Comment: @AdityaJain: There's no such thing as `document.onready`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moment you load your script element with `id=moo` hasn't created yet. So `var boo = document.getElementById("moo");` can't find any element. Try loading your script afte DOM is created.

In the second code your DOM has been created at the time you call the function so `var boo = document.getElementById("moo");` can find the element and it is working as you expected.

For first code try:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="moo">
    <li>loo</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

var newElement = document.createElement("li");
newElement.innerHTML = "hello";
var boo = document.getElementById("moo");
boo.appendChild(newElement);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is caused by the fact you're executing the script at the top of the page. At that time the DOM is not yet parsed and the script will not be able to find the element with id `moo`.

Therefore, put the script at the bottom of the page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="moo">
    <li>loo</li>
</ul>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var newElement = document.createElement("li");
newElement.innerHTML = "hello";
var boo = document.getElementById("moo");
boo.appendChild(newElement);

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When Javascript tries to execute this line
`var boo = document.getElementById("moo");`
the element with id="moo" does not exist yet. Try to move all your JS code before closing `</body>`